# Валидация на bootstrap+jquery validate

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

День добрый.
В чём суть: делаю форму, подключил плагин [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org) для валидации

Получилась такая форма где всё работает:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Форма</title>

</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").validate({
      rules: {
        login: {
            required: true,
          rangelength: [5, 20]

          },

        }
    });
  });

  </script>
  <h1>HTUTU</h1>
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <label class="lab" for="login">Имя </label><input type="text" name="login" value=""><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Однако если делаю на **bootstrap'e** вот так:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Первый шаблон</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
      login: {
          required: true,
        rangelength: [5, 20]

        },

      }
  });
});
</script>

<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row otstup">    
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>Обычная форма</h2>
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="login">login</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" value="" placeholder="Введите login">
            </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Войти</button>
           </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Не работает. Где в коде я мог допустить ошибку???

Comment: Теги сбились...

Comment: форма в форме у вас, нельзя так

Answer (score 1):

Не следует смешивать несколько версий jQuery. Я предложил правку к Вашему вопросу где поместил код в сниппеты, убрал инициацию нескольких версий jQuery и всё заработало.